# HTTP request Integer Overflow NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer-overflow

I'm trying to send a HTTP request using the `request` library in nodejs. However I'm not able to send `401450000000494382` id as a POST parameter as Node truncates it to `401450000000494400`.

Comment: where do you get this "integer" in the first place, since it's greater than javascripts MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, I'm guessing the number was originally a string somewhere

Comment: It's an ID parameter required by the API.

Comment: And, any POST parameter is going to be a string too.  It seems like either you're confused about your id being a number and it's actually supposed to be a string or you really need to understand the feasibility of using numbers that are larger than node.js supports natively and perhap investigate a big number library that uses its own format.

Comment: just don't "store" or "use" it likes it's a number ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max value of a number type is 9007199254740991 in javascript/Node.js
So it's not possible to pass by 'number' type.
Just send value as string type and change the operations accordingly.

Comment: Uhhh, the node.js server can't convert it to a number.  It's Javascript with the same max value limitations.

Comment: @jfriend00  since we have no info about the API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the number because the result that he gives is bigger than the original.Because every number high than 9007199254740991 will lost the precision.
So you can use this code.

```
    var bignum = require('bignum');


    var p = bignum(401450000000494382).sub(19).add(1);

    console.log(p.toString());
```

try it here 
https://npm.runkit.com/bignum